# How to use form value without submitting the form to same page or to other page in php

Tags: javascript, php

```
    // I want to use a form value with out submitting to a page or within the same page
    //Javscript

    <script language='javascript'>

    function L()
    {
//Here am setting the value for the hidden filed
 document.getElementById('ide').value='VALUE';
    }

    </script>

    // Here i want to echo out the value of hidden field


    <body onload=L()>
    <?PHP
    echo "<input type='hidden' id='ide'>";

    //Here i want to echo out the value of hidden field
    //How can i do dat using PHP      
    ?>
    </body>
```

`enter code here`// Here i want to echo out the value of hidden field
        // I want to use a form value with out submitting to a page or within the same page
        // I want to use a form value with out submitting to a page or within the same page

Comment: THere is still garbage comments n your question. Remove it please

Answer (score 1):

First thing, if it is a hidden field, how do you expect it to show the value.

Your code is correct, just change hidden to text as below,

```
    <script type="text/javascript" language='javascript'>
        function setValue()
        {
             document.getElementById('ide').value = 'your value is 10';
        }
    </script>

    <body onload=setValue()>
    <?php
        echo "<input type='text' value='' id='ide'>";
    ?>
    </body>
```

Better use a div or span as below,

```
    <script type="text/javascript" language='javascript'>
        function setValue()
        {
             document.getElementById('ide').innerHTML = 'your value is 10';
        }
    </script>

    <body onload=setValue()>
    <?php
        echo "<span id='ide'></span>";
    ?>
    </body>
```

Comment: I want to use that value for sql query in the where condition is that possible.

Comment: Am able to c the content of span tag but am not able to use that in the sql query

Comment: i am trying it via ajax, give me few mins

Comment: This is the Jquery i used $(document).ready(function(){

$(".sameclass").click(function (e) {

    e.preventDefault();
    var QS = $(this).attr('href').split('?');
    if(QS.length>0){
        var val = QS[1].split('=');

        if(val.length>0){
          $("#edit_prdct").hide().slideDown('slow');
    document.getElementById('prd_id').value=val[1];
        }    
    }
});

});

Comment: <DIV id='list_prdct'>
Product1&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="dum.php?id=1" calss='sameclass'>Edit</a><br />
Product2&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="dum.php?id=2" calss='sameclass'>Edit</a><br />
Product3&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="dum.php?id=3" calss='sameclass'>Edit</a><br />
Product4&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="dum.php?id=4" calss='sameclass'>Edit</a><br />

</DIV>

Comment: <DIV id="edit_prdct">

<?PHP
$prdid"<input type=hidden id='prd_id' value=''>";
//Here i want to use that value of the hidden field as the condition in the mysql qry




?>

</DIV>

Comment: and i saved dat page as dum.php

Comment: you are getting data in your url, see, var QS = $(this).attr('href').split('?'); so why are you not using $_GET[] directly

Comment: If am using $_GET[] its not getting anything i think we cannot do that i went for the ajax post method and i solved yaar but thoda yeh hai ki i couldnt done that as i thought Hmmmmmmm.  Any way thanks boss i keep in touch with u, u tried to solve my prob thank boss. Take Care

Answer (score 0):

you do realize that PHP is a server side scripting language right? The PHP code you write is parsed into HTML in the web server, So you must submit it to a web page, If you want to do it without submitting to a webpage you should use java script ( jQuery ).